# Поиск индексов повторяющихся элементов списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список, и мне нужно знать индекс определенного элемента.
Например:

```
wordToCheck = "Маша"
list = ['Маша', 'Саша', 'Маша', 'Петя', 'Ваня', 'Маша']
```

То есть в данном списке, мне нужны индексы - 0, 2, 5

Comment: А если Петь будет двое?

Comment: @MBo хоть угодно сколько, но ищем только машу

Comment: Так определитесь. Вам нужны *индексы каждого повторяющегося элемента* или индексы слова "Маша"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужны индексы именно элементов "Маша":

```
s = ['Маша', 'Саша', 'Маша', 'Петя', 'Ваня', 'Маша']

x = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == "Маша"]
print(x)   #  [0, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь можно создать словарь, в котором по ключу будут храниться список с индексами

```
a = {}
index = 0

mlist = ['Маша', 'Саша', 'Маша', 'Петя', 'Ваня', 'Маша', 'Ваня', 'Саша']

for i in mlist:
    if i in a:
        a[i].append(index)
    else:
        a[i] = [index]

    index += 1

for i in a.keys():
    if len(a[i]) > 1:
        print(a[i])
```

Comment: Если этот ответ решает вашу проблему, нажмите на галочку слева

Comment: Не совсем тот вид, что мне нужен, мне просто нужен список индексов [0, 2, 5], на которых располагается слово "Маша"

Comment: @ck1e По этому словарю можно найти все повторяющиеся имена, просто спомощью цикла for обойти его и найти списки, в которых более одного элемента. Вопрос был поставлен не совсем корректно, мне не известно сколько имён может повторяться!

Comment: Может повторяться только маша, есть какой-то способ получить список индексов [0, 2, 5]?

Comment: @ck1e   Я исправил код, всё решается очень просто, если будут повторяться другие имена, они так же выведутся

Comment: Если этот ответ решает вашу проблему, нажмите на галочку слева

Answer (score 0):

```
mlist = ['Маша', 'Саша', 'Маша', 'Петя', 'Ваня', 'Маша', 'Ваня', 'Саша']
wordToCheck = "Маша"
a = {}
index = 0
count = 0

for i in mlist:
  if wordToCheck == i:
    a[index] = count
    index += 1
  count += 1
print(a)
```

Вывод:

> {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 5}